# What would be the best way to store csv data that my web app users upload, as to then perform pandas analysis and display them using flask?

Tags: python, csv, flask, heroku, shopify

I am quite new to the web application world. I am using flask at the moment to attempt to make a shopify application.

So I have an app that authenticates users (or stores) through shopify. They can then upload a csv file (let's say between 10 000 and 200 000 rows with 4columns) from which I create new data and display them with an option to download the new csv files.

I first made a flask app running locally, without authentification and using globals so I can access the uploaded csv in different routes, functions... It works well but I am aware this could not work on a server, especially with different users using the app.

My idea is to use a storage, get the data back in the app, perform some tasks and save small tables in the user session to be displayed. If the user wants to download the whole csv I got from the tasks, I run the task again on the download button and launch the download.

So my questions are as follow:

Am I taking the right angle for this task or are there other, better, solutions?

What database would you advice me to use for such file storage per user? In particular, is one better suited for this kind of usage and easier to integrate in flask than others?

Answer (score 1):

Cloud storage is quite cheap these days. S3 or Azure Blob Store or whatever can be used. You can calculate your costs using their pricing model available on their websites. There are different tiers of storage you can opt for (cold, warm, hot) depending on how quickly/frequently you expect to retrieve the data.

Just make sure you have a good organization/naming scheme for the files so you can easily retrieve them and there are no filename clashes.

You can also use a DB that has the ability to store blobs. Costs will depend on how the database is hosted and who is charging for it and how.